# create a bar chart with chartjs 3.9.1

Tags: javascript, charts

How do you create this structure from code at runtime?

```
datasets: [{
 label: "Apples",
 backgroundColor: "#AF7",
 data: [Math.random() * 100],
},{
     label: "Oranges",
     backgroundColor: "#FA4",
     data: [Math.random() * 100],
  },{
     label: "Mangos",
     backgroundColor: "#FF7",
     data: [Math.random() * 100],
  },{
     label: "Avocados",
     backgroundColor: "#2A7",
     data: [Math.random() * 100],
  }]
```

Comment: Do you use any javascript framework? Like Angular, AngularJS, Rect, Vue,...?

Comment: No, pure javascript